Is it redundant to have a function to load all the file not in the dist folder in a Vite React Project?
Before I say what the problem is could I get some links to some resources that help me understand how Vite build files and how the whole build process works? Especially when it comes to the asset files like index-xxxx.js and how they update and whether or not they can be include outside of the dist folder.
So I have this function which loads files that are not in the dist folder. It takes two arguments the generated project/dist/assets/index-xxxx.js file and project/dist/assets/index-xxxx.css file. The function is basically the script crossorigin module tag and link to css file tag just written in js. Is this redundant at all? Like the dist folder already gets loaded anyways and supposedly the problem with the function is that the call looks like this loadFiles(project/dist/assets/index-xxxx.js', 'project/dist/assets/index-xxxx.css') So every time the project gets built the filenames do not update.
So one solution was to try to copy those asset files and have consistent names. But then I thought why would I copy generated file contents? That makes no sense. So what do I have to do to make sure the filenames update? Or is this function just not doing what I think its doing?

Vite under the hood uses rollup, you can see the documentation on this here https://vitejs.dev/guide/build. You may also want to look at the static asset handling https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html
